# Bootstrap Footer not Sticking to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.5 to display a footer at the bottom of webpages using the .navbar navbar-default class. On pages which are displaying a list of items greater than 10 the footer is being displayed correctly at the bottom of the page but on pages having less than 5 items then the footer is being displayed at the middle of the page instead of the bottom.

**HTML code**..

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-bottom:0px;padding-botton:0px">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbarBottom">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbarBottom">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
                        <li><a href="https://www.linkA.com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.linkB.com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.linkC.com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></span> How It Works</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.linkD.com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-certificate"></span> Credits</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.linkE.com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://www.linkF.com" target="_blank"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span><b style="color:blue;"> Survey</b></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

After changing the navbar class to "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" the footer is fixed to the bootom of the page but I'm not able to scroll down to the last item of the list. Please help..

Comment: The example you posted seems to work fine, if you're applying any other CSS/JS you should post it.

Comment: You have to set `min-height` of the list of items, will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
.navbar{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok so if you want footer to stick on scroll

then

```
.navbar
{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

and if you just want footer

```
.navbar
    {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    }
```